# Array with two classes

Tags: c#, java, arrays

Hi im doing a school assignment, and I need to convert this JAVA code to C#

```
private Map<ItemID, ProductDescription> descriptions = new HashMap()<ItemID, ProductDescription>;
```

Is it possible to make a straight conversion?

I've already decided to make ItemID into an int, and ProductDescription is a class.

Comment: If ItemID is a class, why convert it to an int? Can you? Is it a class containing one int field?

Comment: So why doesn't the code read `Map<Integer..`?

Comment: Do you need to support `null` keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can.
Please look into following examples:

```
IDictionary<int, string> h = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            h.Add(1, "a");
            h.Add(2, "b");
            h.Add(3, "c");

SortedList<int, string> s = new SortedList<int, string>();
            s.Add(1, "a");
            s.Add(2, "b");
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Dictionary<int, ProductDescription>` instead.

[`Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Represents a collection of keys and values. The key must be unique.

Comment: It's close, but not exaclty the same: [`java.util.HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) permits `null` values and the `null` key.

Comment: @Paolo Dictionary also allows null values. Only the one null key entry is not supported

Answer (score 1):

```
private Dictionary<ItemID, ProductDescription> descriptions = new Dictionary<ItemID, ProductDescription>();
```

The hasmap indeed allows for one null key entry. In the (rare?) case you would need this I'd simply create a special ItemID and use that for the null key.

You could ofcourse make a dictionary descendant with null key support, but that would be overdoing it imho ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just replace `HashMap` with [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). You might want to type the variable as an [`IDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) (in the same spirit as the Java code), but that's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do the conversion using a Dictionary instead of HashMap. And of course it is more effective to get the idea of each code segment and convert. Trying to convert line by line is not recommended since you may miss a better way that can be used to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good match but,

```
private IDictionary<ItemID, ProductDescription> descriptions
    = new Dictionary<ItemID, ProductDescription>();
```

---

**Note**

[`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) will accept `null` key values, where as [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) will not.

If you really want to support `null` key values, I'd like to see you reasoning before attempting a perfect .Net `HashMap` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options.

There is an

[Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) in C#

[KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) So it can be `List<KeyValuePair<T,U>>`

[Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) //Preferred